# Can I add metadata to a transfer operation?

Tags: operation, transfer

is it possible to add a unique identifier to a transfer operation? We want to be able to better track payments to our delegators.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no you can't as your delegators would be using standard KT1 accounts to receive their funds which means you're limited with what you can do with it.

You can capture the operation hash when injecting and use that in exchange with the tzscan API.

Comment: I just remember reading some improvement to the protocol to allow for metadata properties. But that's only for tz1 account then? Thx.